# linq to sql (VS 2010) - insert doesn't work

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a class containing my data context:

```
private static drDataContext db = new drDataContext();
```

I also have the method:

```
public static void InsertSelfRatings(List<DeveloperSelfRating> ratings)
    {

        foreach (DeveloperSelfRating sr in ratings)
        {
            db.DeveloperSelfRatings.InsertOnSubmit(sr);
        }

        // db.DeveloperSelfRatings.InsertAllOnSubmit(ratings);

        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

I tried both InsertOnSubmit() and InsertAllOnSubmit() and I encounter the same problem - only the last record (DeveloperSelfRating object) in the 'ratings' list is being inserted into the database.

What might be the reason for this problem?

Thanks !!!

Comment: check you ratings collection is it having the records more than 1 and all are different...

Comment: check out this article - I think it may shed some light:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/994e75cb-f651-4a2a-aa4a-39de7fa2fd1b

Comment: Try to go back to InsertAllOnSubmit. That should work. If not, profile and see what SQL is being generated. The ratings you add are all new? Does your DB use Identity as PK?

Comment: @Pranay Rana: Thanks a lot!!! silly me! my problem was with the list I pass to the method!

Comment: Is `DeveloperSelfRating` a class or a struct?

Answer (score 0):

You just put this line db.SubmitChanges(); in foreach loop like

public static void InsertSelfRatings(List ratings)

{

```
    foreach (DeveloperSelfRating sr in ratings)
    {
        db.DeveloperSelfRatings.InsertOnSubmit(sr);
        db.SubmitChanges();

    }



}
```

Because when u insert one record in linq you have to do submit changes so after every insert you have to write db.SubmitChanges(); 
just try this ok

Comment: `because when u insert one record in linq you have to do submit changes` <-- Not true, Linq to SQL keeps an internal list of changes, so you can submit at the end.

Comment: @Michael Stum : But if we have to insert all the record by creating list and after that we have to write InsertAllOnSubmit()